# Join two data frames and add NAs for missing values of joining column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to join two data frames using `dplyr` `left_join`. The code is provided below:

```
file = c('f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9', 'f10', 'f11', 'f12', 'f13', 'f14', 'f15')
word_count = c(14806, 804, 168, 27172, 782, 699, 1891, 64385, 738, 9497, 74, 181183, 173, 37, 2321)
wc_df <- cbind.data.frame(file, word_count)
variant = c('bcause', 'bcos', 'bcos', 'bcos', 'bcos', 'bcos', 'bcos', 'bcos', 'bcos', 'bcos', 'bcus', 'bcus', 'bcus', 'because', 'because', 'because', 'because', 'because', 'because', 'because', 'because', 'because', 'because', 'becos', 'becos', 'becos', 'becos', 'becos', 'becos', 'becos', 'becos', 'becos', 'bicos', 'cos', 'cos', 'cos', 'cos', 'cos', 'cos', 'cos', 'cos', 'cos', 'cus', 'cus', 'cus', 'cus', 'cus', 'cuz', 'cuz', 'cuz', 'cuz', 'cuz', 'cuz', 'cz')
file = c('f1',  'f1',  'f2',  'f3',  'f4',  'f5',  'f6',  'f7',  'f8',  'f9',  'f10',  'f11',  'f12',  'f1',  'f2',  'f3',  'f4',  'f5',  'f6',  'f7',  'f8',  'f9',  'f10',  'f1',  'f2',  'f3',  'f4',  'f5',  'f6',  'f7',  'f8',  'f9',  'f10',  'f1',  'f2',  'f3',  'f4',  'f5',  'f6',  'f7',  'f8',  'f9',  'f1',  'f2',  'f3',  'f4',  'f5',  'f6',  'f7',  'f8',  'f9',  'f10',  'f11',  'f12')
freq = c(2,  14,  3,  1,  3,  11,  14,  5,  19,  4,  2,  1,  1,  23,  2,  51,  1,  1,  4,  52,  2,  29,  4,  7,  3,  1,  112,  12,  7,  7,  2,  8,  646,  15,  1,  1,  7,  9,  1,  13,  14,  11,  1,  6,  1,  4,  2,  4,  5,  2,  3,  1,  3,  1)
freq_df <- cbind.data.frame(file, variant, freq)
new_df <- left_join(freq_df, wc_df)
```

As it can be seen the `file` column is being used to join the two data frames. The problem is that `freq_df` will always have a few values (or levels) missing for `file`. So it is observable that `wc_df` has 15 levels of `file`, but `freq_df` only has 12 of the same. When I join these two using the above mentioned `dplyr` function, the values/levels of `file` that are not available in the first data frame are lost.
After searching around I came across the `complete()` function from `tidyr`. I can apply it as follows to get the missing combinations of existing `file` and `variant` (12 * 10 = 120 rows) as follows:

```
 new_df <- left_join(freq_df, wc_df) %>% tidyr::complete(file, variant, fill = list(freq = 0))
```

However, I want to get the missing values/levels of `file` (from `wc_df` as well) in the `new_df`, where the combinations of `variant` and `file` will have an NA (or 0) in the third column `freq` (and the total number of rows will be 15 * 10 = 150). 
How can I do it?

Comment: Can you make your example a bit shorter (with 5-10 rows) and show expected output for what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand the question, but it sounds like you need `dplyr::full_join()` instead of `dplyr::left_join` to preserve non-matched values of `file` from either of the two joined data frames.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the above answer with `full_join`, I have come up with a solution to solve my problem. The `full_join` will introduce NAs in `freq` and `variant` columns. I replace the NAs in each column step-by-step as follows:

```
new_df <- full_join(freq_df, wc_df) %>% %>% as.data.frame() #Full join and convert to data frame
#replace NAs with previous values
new_df <- tidyr::fill(new_df, variant) #Not converting to a data frame above causes an error that the column cannot be modified because it is a grouping variable
#NAs in freq column are simply replaced by zeroes
new_df$freq <- replace(new_df$freq, is.na(new_df$freq), 0)
```

Now all of the values of the joining column `file` are present in the `new_df`. The NAs introduced have been manually patched.